# Заполнение ComboBox из List<string> из кода

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть код, беру имена всех картинок в гриде и записываю в `List`. Потом  для `combobox` задаю этот `List` как источник данных. Он заполняется, но имена не отображает.
В XAML написал:

```
DisplayMemberPath="Name"
```

Потому что я брал имена `Image`. Список заполняет, но не отображает:

```
public void InputImage()
{
    var children = grid.Children;
    foreach (var child in children) 
    {
        var image  = child as Image;
        if (image is Image) 
        {
            Names.Add(image.Name);
        }
    }
    imglist.ItemsSource = Names;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В XAML уберите `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` и не надо лишних классов.

Или проще, если сам лист Names больше использоваться не будет, не удаляйте `DisplayMemberPath="Name"` из XAML а метод `InputImage` будет таким

```
public void InputImage()
{
    imglist.ItemsSource = grid.Children.OfType<Image>();
}
```

Comment: Вот интересно кто минус поставил

Comment: Не я. Вопрос должен звучать, не "кто" , а "за что".

Comment: Согласен) за что?)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением класса:

```
public class ImageName 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public void InputImage()
{
    var children = grid.Children;
    foreach (var child in children) 
    {
        var image  = child as Image;
        if (image is Image) 
        {
            Names.Add(new ImageName { Name = image.Name});
        }
    }
    imglist.ItemsSource = Names;
}
```